# How can i get Current User's permission levels, Current User's SharePoint group by code (Javascript especially)?

Tags: javascript, permissions, item-level-permissions

I want to get Current User's SharePoint groups by programmatically.How can i get this information?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below ajax call for getting groups of current user.

```
function getAllGroups(){
return jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups&$select=groups/Title",
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
});
}

getAllGroups().then(
    function(data){
    var groupArray = new Array();
    jQuery.each(data.d.Groups.results, function (i, result) {
    alert(result.Title);
        groupArray.push(result.Title);
    });
  },function(data){
    alert('fail');
 });
```

Comment: Allright , for domain groups , does it works?

Comment: No its only for SharePoint groups. There is no direct way of getting domain group using javascipt. for more you can refer https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4afca004-dba7-47d0-b023-146c475b18a3/how-to-get-ad-group-users-in-csom-in-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the same with popular [PnPjs](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs) library:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.web.currentUser.select('groups/Title').expand('groups').get()
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.Groups);
});
```